# Python 3: Operators -IndentationError

Tags: python

This code produces an IndentationError at the line

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

I would appreciate if someone can explain the reason and solution to compile the code

```py
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the solve function below.
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):

if __name__ == '__main__'
    meal_cost = float(input())

    tip_percent = int(input())

    tax_percent = int(input())

    solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent)

tip = meal_cost * tip_percent

tax = meal_cost * tax_percent

total = meal_cost + tip + tax
```

Comment: you forgot indentation on line `if __name__ == '__main__'` and also missing `:` in same line

Comment: Just put : after ```if __name__ == '__main__'``` and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You miss-indented the line by four spaces, also forgot `:` colon, also changed the order, try changing the function to:

```
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):
    meal_cost = float(input())

    tip_percent = int(input())

    tax_percent = int(input())

    solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    tip = meal_cost * tip_percent

    tax = meal_cost * tax_percent

    total = meal_cost + tip + tax
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this function was incorrectly separated from its body:

```
# Complete the solve function below.
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):
    tip = meal_cost * tip_percent

    tax = meal_cost * tax_percent

    total = meal_cost + tip + tax

if __name__ == '__main__':
    meal_cost = float(input())

    tip_percent = int(input())

    tax_percent = int(input())

    solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent)
```